# Handling numbers with standard error in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I needed to handle a lot of numbers with standard errors, so I wrote a class that handles them parametrically (below, taken from [larger module](https://github.com/matteoferla/mutagenesis)) as to the best of my knowledge there was nothing out there and the maths worked well for me in the past. I was happy with it, until someone recently mentioned that numpy has something like that, but wasn't sure about —the chap has limited knowledge, but pretends otherwise, so I am fairly sure it is not true. However, greed beats wisdom, so I am still going hunting for an epic hidden super amazing class (ideally solving them empirically). Not to mention, Scipy and Numpy are a tad confusing at times.

Therefore I would like to know whether I have reinvented the wheel or not.

This is the class, just for reference —it works, so feel free to copypaste.

```
class NumSEM:
    """
    A class to handle numbers with SEM.
    I am not sure why there is nothing that does this and whether this is the best way of doing.
    For now errors are propagated parametrically based on the maths I discuss in [mutanalyst](http://www.mutanalyst.com/)
    """
    option_space_between_numbers = True

    def __init__(self, num, sem, df=2):
        """
        :param num: the number (mean)
        :param sem: the standard error
        :param df: the number of samples used to determine the SE
        :return: an object with the three inputs as _num, _sem and _df attributes.
        """
        self._num = float(num)
        self._sem = float(sem)
        self._df = int(df)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        The lowest digit to show is the first digit of the error. So math.floor(math.log10(se))
        :return:
        """
        if self.option_space_between_numbers:
            s = " "
        else:
            s = ""
        if self._sem == 0:

            return str(self._num) + s + "±" + s + "Ind."
        else:
            sig = -math.floor(math.log10(self._sem))
            if sig < 0:
                sig = 0
            txt = "{:." + str(sig) + "f}" + s + "±" + s + "{:." + str(sig) + "f}"
            return txt.format(self._num, self._sem)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        Returns the addition of either two NumSEM objects or a NumSEM and a float/int
        :param other: NumSEM or int or float
        :return: a new NumSEM instance where the variance is based on the Binaymé rule if both NumSEM.
        """
        if type(other) is NumSEM:
            v = self._var() + other._var()
            df = NumSEM._df(self._df, other._df)
            return NumSEM(self._num + other._num, math.sqrt(v / df), df)
        else:  # assume int or float
            return NumSEM(self._num + other, self._sem, self._df)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """
        Returns the subtraction of either two NumSEM objects or a NumSEM and a float/int
        :param other: NumSEM or int or float
        :return: a new NumSEM instance where the variance is based on the Binaymé rule (var summed) if both NumSEM.
        """
        if type(other) is NumSEM:
            v = self._var() + other._var()
            df = NumSEM._df(self._df, other._df)
            return NumSEM(self._num - other._num, math.sqrt(v / df), df)
        else:  # assume int or float
            return NumSEM(self._num - other, self._sem, self._df)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """
        Returns the mutiplication of either two NumSEM objects or a NumSEM and a float/int
        :param other: NumSEM or int or float
        :return: a new NumSEM instance where, if both NumSEM, the variance is the var(x)/mean(x)^2 + var(y)/mean(y)^2.
        The latter formula stems from the first order Taylor approximation of the König–Huygens theorem applied to a function:
        > Var(f(x))\approx [f'(x)]^2 · Var(x)
        And converting Var(xy) to Var(e^ln(xy)) and solving.
        > Var(e^ln(xy)) = (e^ln(xy))^2 · Var(ln(xy)) = x^2 · y^2 · (Var(ln(x))+Var(ln(y))) = x^2 · y^2 · (Var(x)/x^2+Var(y)/y^2) _etc._
        """
        if type(other) is NumSEM:
            v = self._var() * other._num ** 2 + other._var() * self._num ** 2
            df = NumSEM._df(self._df, other._df)
            return NumSEM(self._num * other._num, math.sqrt(v / df), df)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        """
        Same principle as multiplication
        :param other: NumSEM or int or float
        :return: a new NumSEM instance where, if both NumSEM, the variance is the var(x)/mean(y)^2 + var(y)*mean(x)^2/mean(y)^4.
        """
        if type(other) is NumSEM:
            v = self._var() / other._num ** 2 + other._var() * self._num ** 2 / other._num ** 4
            df = NumSEM._df(self._df, other._df)
            return NumSEM(self._num / other._num, math.sqrt(v / df), df)

    def _var(self):
        return self._sem ** 2 * self._df

    @staticmethod
    def _df(a, b):
        return min(a,
                   b)  # I am unsure if min is best, hence the method. I assume that the worst case scenario is the smallest.
        # Also it is not degrees of freedom but sample size...
```

Comment: My answer pointing to `uncertainties.unumpy` was deleted by @MartjinPieters. I don't really know why he deleted it, but I still think this is exactly the ["epic hidden super amazing class"](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/numpy_guide.html) you are looking for.

Comment: @NichtJens, Thanks for leaving it as a comment despite the typical SO toxic environment. &mdash;Ha! I discovered tactical downswiping with the first answer I gave and never bothered answering in SO again. I hope that the user pettiness does not kill SO like it did in the now stagnant Wikipedia, where only ridiculous new rules are introduced.

Comment: What should I say: I feel this was what you asked for. If @Martijn thinks your question is a valid one, then my answer should be valid, too. But, never mind, does that package actually help you?